# Iterated integrals over an indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $E:=[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and let $S:=\{(x,y)\in E \ | \ x\in \mathbb{Q}, y\in \mathbb{Q}\} $.  Now, say we have $$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 1, & (x,y)\in S \\ 0, & (x,y)\in E\backslash S \end{cases}$$
I've been told that $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dxdy, \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dydx$$ are both equal to $0$ but was never given a good explanation as to why.  Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: this function is not Riemann integrable so you must understand the iterated integrals in the context of Lebesgue integration. In this context the set $S$ have measure zero so the integrals are zero

Comment: Moreover, $f$ is bounded and $E$ is compact, so by Tonelli's theorem $f$ is integrable over $E$ and hence the integral $$\iint_E f(x,y)\ \mathsf d(x\times y)$$ is finite and equal to the iterated integrals.

Comment: To add a little to Masacroso's remark, $S$ is countable, and all countable sets in $\Bbb R^n$ have Lebesgue measure $0$, This is because Lebesgue measure is countably additive (If $\{U_n\}$ is a sequence of disjoint measurable sets, then $\mu\left(\bigcup_n U_n\right) =\sum_n \mu(U_n)$), and measure of a single point is $0$.